# Not getting result when deserializing json using DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I have following json:

```
{
  "Australia": {
    "count": 2,
    "records": {
      "File1.ppt": {
        "id": "123456789"
      },
      "File2.doc": {
        "id": "987654321"
      }
    }
  },
  "PDFs.zip": {
    "count": 0,
    "records": {}
  },
  "Peru": {
    "count": 2,
    "records": {
      "File3.PPT": {
        "id": "897456123"
      },
      "File4.PPT": {
        "id": "123546789"
      }
    }
  },
  "total count": 4
}
```

and to deserialize the above json I have defined some classes so that I can use these classes while deserializing my json into objects and below are the classes:

```
namespace GEO_Batch_Creation
{
    [DataContract]
    class BhpIdJson
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "objects")]
        public Dictionary<string, Country[]> Countries { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "total count")]
        public int TotalCount { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    class Country
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "count")]
        public int Count { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "records")]
        public Dictionary<string, Record> Records { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    class Record
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "filename")]
        public string FileName { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "id")]
        public Dictionary<string, string> BhpId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But when I use following code to deserialize the json I am getting only total count.

```
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
    {
        // Deserialization from JSON  
        DataContractJsonSerializer deserializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(BhpIdJson));
        BhpIdJson bsObj2 = (BhpIdJson)deserializer.ReadObject(ms);                
    }
```

Please suggest me where I am doing mistake.

Comment: I'd suggest using JSON.NET, and https://app.quicktype.io?share=4Jf5zFTxMJF2iOu62REc .

Comment: your json doesn't have `objects` property

Comment: Where was this json generated from as it doesn't match your c# classes in any way

Comment: Please suggest me if there is any problem in C# classes I will fix it. Actually someone had suggested that for root element you can write like this.

Comment: Did you look at the link I suggested?

Comment: Thanks mjwills. The link you suggested is very useful. However for the sake of my knowledge I would like to know is there any possibility to de-serialize it using DataContractJsonSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this JSON is in correct format. I don't know if you got this from somewhere or made for yourself, but if the last one I recommend you to change the structure.
Even in C# you cant realy create a class that has the objects and the count of the object in the same List or Array etc.
Based on your class your JSON yhould look like this:

```
{
  "objects": [
    {
      "name": "Australia",
      "count": 2,
      "records": [
        {
          "fileName": "File1.ppt",
          "id": "123456789"
        },
        {
          "fileName": "File2.doc",
          "id": "987654321"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "total count": 4
}
```

As you can see you have to add Name or something to your Country class. I hope it helped.

**Edit:**
You can create a list like I mentioned above but it's not a good practice I think.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I got this json from my client so I don't have option to change the json. However I have option to change my code which deserialize it.

Comment: If you get this from your client that means that the client doesn't really understand the format of JSON messages. The problem is that you have to make a own deserializer because every deserializer (like Newtonsoft) will throw an exception.

Comment: Yeah you are right i was mistaken. However it's not really usable because the entity's "classname" is the name of the country and non of the third party deserializer will able to deserialize it to a C# object for you.